# pipenv install --ignore-pipfile creates a Pipfile with no packages

Tags: python, pipenv

I want to move the program to another environment, eg A to B.

1. At A, I first issue **pipenv lock** to update the Pipfile.lock.
2. I copy the Pipfile.lock from A to B.
3. At B, I issue **pipenv install --ignore-pipfile** to create the new environment from the Pipfile.lock.  I notice that it will also create a Pipfile but without any packages in the [package] section.

Is this the correct behaviour ?  I find the Pipfile misleading if I were to read it as it does not reflect the packages installed.

Should I delete it or I should keep it ?

Or I've made a mistake in my procedure ?

Thanks very much !

Comment: In short, you must always have a `Pipfile` and you will have a `Pipfile.lock` most of the time. While this behavior is somewhat confusing and poorly documented, `--ignore-pipfile` creates a `Pipfile` because `pipenv` always needs that to exist. See this answer for more info: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52951378. Do note the comments under that answer as well.

Comment: @kalatabe Thanks. So the point is Pipfile is always present.  In my case, its not use but is generated.  My concern is that it does not reflect the actual environment and is misleading.  Any idea how I could generate a proper Pipfile to reflect the true environment ?

Comment: Creating a new environment should be done with the Pipfile present, and optionally the Pipfile.lock. Don't just move the lock file.

Comment: @kalatabe ic, I probably had the misunderstanding that Pipfile is for development because I can update it and Pipfile.lock is to move to production because it's a "lock" (I thought it locks the environment as in baselining it).  So I just move the Pipfile.lock over (the baseline).  So now I would move both Pipfile and Pipfile.lock over.

Comment: Moving the Pipfile over to non-production environment, do people usually remove the development section from the Pipfile or move the Pipfile over intact ?

Comment: `pipenv install` by default does not install `[dev-packages]`, only `pipenv install -d` does that: `-d, --dev                Install both develop and default packages.  [env
                           var: PIPENV_DEV]` . So as long as you build your production deploys without `-d` you won't get any dev-time dependencies installed.