# virtualenv install packages (activate virtual environment first) vs pipenv install packages (activate virtual environment later)?

Tags: python, virtualenv, pipenv, pyvenv

**virtualenv**

We will activate the virtual environment first and then run `pip install ...` to install packages for virtual environment.

See the document, https://packaging.python.org/guides/installing-using-pip-and-virtual-environments/

- `source env/bin/activate`
- Now that you’re in your virtual environment you can install packages. Let’s install the excellent Requests library from the Python Package Index (PyPI):

  ```
  pip install requests
  ```

But pipenv is different.

**pipenv**

As for pipenv, the instruction here, [Please explain the usage of Pipfile and Pipfile.lock](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46330327/please-explain-the-usage-of-pipfile-and-pipfile-lock)

Before we activate the virtual environment,

- We could run `pipenv install` to install packages in the project folder first.
- Then we can run `pipenv shell` to activate the virtual environment.

In other words, using virtualenv, we create/activate virtual environment first, and then `pip install ...` packages in virtual environment. But using pipenv, we use `pipenv install ...` to install packages in the project folder first and then use `pipenv shell` to active the environment.

Is this correct?

Answer (score 0):

Er, basically yes.

Virtualenvs change the environment in your current shell, which you can undo with `deactivate`, whereas `pipenv shell` creates a new shell that you need to exit when you have finished.