# Telegram bot on Heroku returns ModuleNotFoundError

Tags: python, heroku, python-telegram-bot

I've built this telegram bot yesterday, and it ran smoothly on Heroku.

However, today I added a new package `python-google-places` and I attempted to push to Heroku but received the following errors in Heroku's log:

```
- 2021-02-24T12:17:55.640900+00:00 app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent call last): 
- 2021-02-24T12:17:55.640926+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "bot.py", line 20, in <module> 
- 2021-02-24T12:17:55.641088+00:00 app[web.1]:     from googleplaces import GooglePlaces, types, lang 
- 2021-02-24T12:17:55.641121+00:00 app[web.1]: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'googleplaces' 
- 2021-02-24T12:17:55.725500+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1 
- 2021-02-24T12:17:55.840225+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
```

I've tried several methods:

1. Manually added `python-google-places==1.4.2` to `requirements.txt`
2. `pip install -r requirements.txt`
3. `heroku plugins:install heroku-builds`
   `heroku builds:cache:purge`
4. `pip freeze > requirements.txt`

`Procfile`:

```
web: python bot.py
```

`Pipfile`

```
[[source]]
url = "https://pypi.org/simple"
verify_ssl = true
name = "pypi"

[packages]
python-telegram-bot = "*"

[dev-packages]

[requires]
python_version = "3.8"
```

`requirements.txt`

```
alabaster==0.7.12
anaconda-client==1.7.2
anaconda-navigator==1.10.0
anaconda-project==0.8.3
appdirs==1.4.4
applaunchservices==0.2.1
appnope @ file:///opt/concourse/worker/volumes/live/0291c9e1-4b15-459f-623e-2770f55be269/volume/appnope_1594338395037/work
appscript @ file:///opt/concourse/worker/volumes/live/50ca4c96-3090-40bb-6981-3a6114ed0af4/volume/appscript_1594840187551/work
APScheduler==3.6.3
argh==0.26.2
argon2-cffi @ file:///opt/concourse/worker/volumes/live/59af29ac-4890-416e-7ab7-794f8d6f7ecd/volume/argon2-cffi_1596828548321/work
asn1crypto @ file:///tmp/build/80754af9/asn1crypto_1596577642040/work
astroid @ file:///opt/concourse/worker/volumes/live/21fd14a9-2a7e-484b-7394-5a9912cdcf80/volume/astroid_1592498459180/work
astropy==4.0.2
async-generator==1.10
atomicwrites==1.4.0
attrs @ file:///tmp/build/80754af9/attrs_1604765588209/work
autopep8 @ file:///tmp/build/80754af9/autopep8_1596578164842/work
Babel @ file:///tmp/build/80754af9/babel_1605108370292/work
backcall==0.2.0
backports.functools-lru-cache==1.6.1
backports.shutil-get-terminal-size==1.0.0
backports.tempfile==1.0
backports.weakref==1.0.post1
beautifulsoup4 @ file:///tmp/build/80754af9/beautifulsoup4_1601924105527/work
bitarray @ file:///opt/concourse/worker/volumes/live/fdfca23e-4dd8-48f7-512d-c4f3db552eeb/volume/bitarray_1605065128338/work
bkcharts==0.2
bleach @ file:///tmp/build/80754af9/bleach_1600439572647/work
bokeh @ file:///opt/concourse/worker/volumes/live/b2253281-9b72-4dcb-624e-e22924b50435/volume/bokeh_1603297849453/work
boto==2.49.0
Bottleneck==1.3.2
brotlipy==0.7.0
certifi==2020.12.5
cffi @ file:///opt/concourse/worker/volumes/live/b9607b09-b777-4ff7-53dc-287727eb8574/volume/cffi_1600699191154/work
chardet==3.0.4
click==7.1.2
cloudpickle @ file:///tmp/build/80754af9/cloudpickle_1598884132938/work
clyent==1.2.2
colorama @ file:///tmp/build/80754af9/colorama_1603211150991/work
conda==4.9.2
conda-build==3.20.5
conda-package-handling @ file:///opt/concourse/worker/volumes/live/a7e34989-4c54-4cb6-4156-4e58ee270730/volume/conda-package-handling_1603018121300/work
conda-verify==3.4.2
contextlib2==0.6.0.post1
cryptography @ file:///opt/concourse/worker/volumes/live/aeb63a26-659e-4edb-5405-74ba8e0c76f2/volume/cryptography_1601046839724/work
cycler==0.10.0
Cython @ file:///opt/concourse/worker/volumes/live/6158b663-a4ca-4e19-7e05-8807e4f79146/volume/cython_1594835048880/work
cytoolz==0.11.0
dask @ file:///tmp/build/80754af9/dask-core_1602083700509/work
decorator==4.4.2
defusedxml==0.6.0
diff-match-patch @ file:///tmp/build/80754af9/diff-match-patch_1594828741838/work
distlib==0.3.1
distributed @ file:///opt/concourse/worker/volumes/live/bd66aa48-5cf5-4b60-6ed4-f204fff153f6/volume/distributed_1605066538557/work
docutils==0.16
entrypoints==0.3
et-xmlfile==1.0.1
fastcache==1.1.0
filelock==3.0.12
flake8 @ file:///tmp/build/80754af9/flake8_1601911421857/work
Flask==1.1.2
fsspec @ file:///tmp/build/80754af9/fsspec_1602684995936/work
future==0.18.2
gevent @ file:///opt/concourse/worker/volumes/live/e6b243ce-c4b8-40bb-4934-ef3bf1c512f2/volume/gevent_1601397552921/work
glob2==0.7
gmpy2==2.0.8
greenlet @ file:///opt/concourse/worker/volumes/live/02d5d57d-1f11-4cf9-580a-19e679c78dc9/volume/greenlet_1600874049903/work
h5py==2.10.0
HeapDict==1.0.1
html5lib @ file:///tmp/build/80754af9/html5lib_1593446221756/work
idna @ file:///tmp/build/80754af9/idna_1593446292537/work
imageio @ file:///tmp/build/80754af9/imageio_1594161405741/work
imagesize==1.2.0
importlib-metadata @ file:///tmp/build/80754af9/importlib-metadata_1602276842396/work
iniconfig @ file:///tmp/build/80754af9/iniconfig_1602780191262/work
intervaltree @ file:///tmp/build/80754af9/intervaltree_1598376443606/work
ipykernel @ file:///opt/concourse/worker/volumes/live/88f541d3-5a27-498f-7391-f2e50ca36560/volume/ipykernel_1596206680118/work/dist/ipykernel-5.3.4-py3-none-any.whl
ipython @ file:///opt/concourse/worker/volumes/live/26969e8f-c9f7-42dc-6ffb-b3effd424c49/volume/ipython_1604101242376/work
ipython-genutils==0.2.0
ipywidgets @ file:///tmp/build/80754af9/ipywidgets_1601490159889/work
isort @ file:///tmp/build/80754af9/isort_1602603989581/work
itsdangerous==1.1.0
jdcal==1.4.1
jedi @ file:///opt/concourse/worker/volumes/live/1c5c293b-9147-4b4b-5a7f-d3f5eddb8470/volume/jedi_1592841952519/work
Jinja2==2.11.2
joblib @ file:///tmp/build/80754af9/joblib_1601912903842/work
json5==0.9.5
jsonschema @ file:///tmp/build/80754af9/jsonschema_1602607155483/work
jupyter==1.0.0
jupyter-client @ file:///tmp/build/80754af9/jupyter_client_1601311786391/work
jupyter-console @ file:///tmp/build/80754af9/jupyter_console_1598884538475/work
jupyter-core==4.6.3
jupyterlab==2.2.6
jupyterlab-pygments @ file:///tmp/build/80754af9/jupyterlab_pygments_1601490720602/work
jupyterlab-server @ file:///tmp/build/80754af9/jupyterlab_server_1594164409481/work
keyring @ file:///opt/concourse/worker/volumes/live/54fc3ec2-338b-44f5-5e13-d62afa6b5820/volume/keyring_1601490916376/work
kiwisolver @ file:///opt/concourse/worker/volumes/live/b8936fa6-0e4b-47e7-4fb4-e02dbd4505ee/volume/kiwisolver_1604014598721/work
lazy-object-proxy==1.4.3
libarchive-c==2.9
llvmlite==0.34.0
locket==0.2.0
lxml @ file:///opt/concourse/worker/volumes/live/9351a723-931c-40fa-7baa-f2f468cdccf6/volume/lxml_1603216287330/work
MarkupSafe @ file:///opt/concourse/worker/volumes/live/cb778296-98db-45ad-411e-6f726e102dc3/volume/markupsafe_1594371638608/work
matplotlib @ file:///opt/concourse/worker/volumes/live/f7797860-f8aa-410c-4a56-72315954816b/volume/matplotlib-base_1603378002957/work
mccabe==0.6.1
mistune @ file:///opt/concourse/worker/volumes/live/95802d64-d39c-491b-74ce-b9326880ca54/volume/mistune_1594373201816/work
mkl-fft==1.2.0
mkl-random==1.1.1
mkl-service==2.3.0
mock==4.0.2
more-itertools @ file:///tmp/build/80754af9/more-itertools_1605111547926/work
mpmath==1.1.0
msgpack==1.0.0
multipledispatch==0.6.0
navigator-updater==0.2.1
nbclient @ file:///tmp/build/80754af9/nbclient_1602783176460/work
nbconvert @ file:///opt/concourse/worker/volumes/live/2b9c1d93-d0fd-432f-7d93-66c93d81b614/volume/nbconvert_1601914875037/work
nbformat @ file:///tmp/build/80754af9/nbformat_1602783287752/work
nest-asyncio @ file:///tmp/build/80754af9/nest-asyncio_1605115881283/work
networkx @ file:///tmp/build/80754af9/networkx_1598376031484/work
nltk @ file:///tmp/build/80754af9/nltk_1592496090529/work
nose @ file:///opt/concourse/worker/volumes/live/a029938e-1732-4cd8-5b98-0542283d158b/volume/nose_1594377915100/work
notebook @ file:///opt/concourse/worker/volumes/live/be0f3504-189d-4bae-4e57-c5d6da73ffcd/volume/notebook_1601501605350/work
numba @ file:///opt/concourse/worker/volumes/live/ae24c1ca-d916-4043-5919-a843fa33e451/volume/numba_1600084276085/work
numexpr==2.7.1
numpy @ file:///opt/concourse/worker/volumes/live/5572694e-967a-4c0c-52cf-b53d43e72de9/volume/numpy_and_numpy_base_1603491881791/work
numpydoc @ file:///tmp/build/80754af9/numpydoc_1605117425582/work
olefile==0.46
openpyxl @ file:///tmp/build/80754af9/openpyxl_1598113097404/work
packaging==20.4
pandas @ file:///opt/concourse/worker/volumes/live/f14cf8c4-c564-4eff-4b17-158e90dbf88a/volume/pandas_1602088128240/work
pandocfilters @ file:///opt/concourse/worker/volumes/live/c330e404-216d-466b-5327-8ce8fe854d3a/volume/pandocfilters_1605120442288/work
parso==0.7.0
partd==1.1.0
path @ file:///opt/concourse/worker/volumes/live/fcdf620c-46d6-4284-4c1e-5b8c3bc6c5c6/volume/path_1596907417277/work
pathlib2 @ file:///opt/concourse/worker/volumes/live/de518564-0d9f-405e-472b-38136f0c2169/volume/pathlib2_1594381084269/work
pathtools==0.1.2
patsy==0.5.1
pep8==1.7.1
pexpect @ file:///opt/concourse/worker/volumes/live/8701bb20-ad87-46c7-5108-30c178cf97e5/volume/pexpect_1594383388344/work
pickleshare @ file:///opt/concourse/worker/volumes/live/93ec39d8-05bb-4f84-7efc-98735bc39b70/volume/pickleshare_1594384101884/work
Pillow @ file:///opt/concourse/worker/volumes/live/991b9a87-3372-4acd-45f9-eaa52701f03c/volume/pillow_1603822262543/work
pipenv==2020.11.15
pkginfo==1.6.1
pluggy==0.13.1
ply==3.11
prometheus-client==0.8.0
prompt-toolkit @ file:///tmp/build/80754af9/prompt-toolkit_1602688806899/work
psutil @ file:///opt/concourse/worker/volumes/live/ff72f822-991c-4030-4f3a-8c41d3ac4e4f/volume/psutil_1598370232375/work
ptyprocess==0.6.0
py @ file:///tmp/build/80754af9/py_1593446248552/work
pycodestyle==2.6.0
pycosat==0.6.3
pycparser @ file:///tmp/build/80754af9/pycparser_1594388511720/work
pycurl==7.43.0.6
pydocstyle @ file:///tmp/build/80754af9/pydocstyle_1598885001695/work
pyflakes==2.2.0
Pygments @ file:///tmp/build/80754af9/pygments_1604103097372/work
pylint @ file:///opt/concourse/worker/volumes/live/ed0164b6-bcc7-4f6b-7dd4-ad89660b5dcb/volume/pylint_1598624018129/work
pyodbc===4.0.0-unsupported
pyOpenSSL @ file:///tmp/build/80754af9/pyopenssl_1594392929924/work
pyparsing==2.4.7
pyrsistent @ file:///opt/concourse/worker/volumes/live/ff11f3f0-615b-4508-471d-4d9f19fa6657/volume/pyrsistent_1600141727281/work
PySocks @ file:///opt/concourse/worker/volumes/live/85a5b906-0e08-41d9-6f59-084cee4e9492/volume/pysocks_1594394636991/work
pytest==0.0.0
python-dateutil==2.8.1
python-google-places==1.4.2
python-jsonrpc-server @ file:///tmp/build/80754af9/python-jsonrpc-server_1600278539111/work
python-language-server @ file:///tmp/build/80754af9/python-language-server_1600454544709/work
python-telegram-bot==13.3
pytz==2021.1
PyWavelets @ file:///opt/concourse/worker/volumes/live/ea36e10f-66e8-43ae-511e-c4092764493f/volume/pywavelets_1601658378672/work
PyYAML==5.3.1
pyzmq==19.0.2
QDarkStyle==2.8.1
QtAwesome @ file:///tmp/build/80754af9/qtawesome_1602272867890/work
qtconsole @ file:///tmp/build/80754af9/qtconsole_1600870028330/work
QtPy==1.9.0
regex @ file:///opt/concourse/worker/volumes/live/7f106f75-0e11-45be-4c20-6b071e37c646/volume/regex_1602786678165/work
requests @ file:///tmp/build/80754af9/requests_1592841827918/work
rope @ file:///tmp/build/80754af9/rope_1602264064449/work
Rtree==0.9.4
ruamel-yaml==0.15.87
scikit-image==0.17.2
scikit-learn @ file:///opt/concourse/worker/volumes/live/111833a2-339b-4578-413b-7337bb8fe64a/volume/scikit-learn_1598376920601/work
scipy @ file:///opt/concourse/worker/volumes/live/851446f6-a052-41c4-4243-67bb78999b49/volume/scipy_1604596178167/work
seaborn @ file:///tmp/build/80754af9/seaborn_1600553570093/work
Send2Trash==1.5.0
simplegeneric==0.8.1
singledispatch @ file:///tmp/build/80754af9/singledispatch_1602523705405/work
six @ file:///opt/concourse/worker/volumes/live/5b31cb27-1e37-4ca5-6e9f-86246eb206d2/volume/six_1605205320872/work
snowballstemmer==2.0.0
sortedcollections==1.2.1
sortedcontainers==2.2.2
soupsieve==2.0.1
Sphinx @ file:///tmp/build/80754af9/sphinx_1597428793432/work
sphinxcontrib-applehelp==1.0.2
sphinxcontrib-devhelp==1.0.2
sphinxcontrib-htmlhelp==1.0.3
sphinxcontrib-jsmath==1.0.1
sphinxcontrib-qthelp==1.0.3
sphinxcontrib-serializinghtml==1.1.4
sphinxcontrib-websupport @ file:///tmp/build/80754af9/sphinxcontrib-websupport_1597081412696/work
spyder @ file:///opt/concourse/worker/volumes/live/93f52c11-6bc0-49a8-541e-aa5e1de1eadc/volume/spyder_1599056974853/work
spyder-kernels @ file:///opt/concourse/worker/volumes/live/b4ec5b57-5b3c-42d0-7731-c0691f88ee81/volume/spyder-kernels_1599056790993/work
SQLAlchemy @ file:///opt/concourse/worker/volumes/live/0214475e-3c0a-49a9-6cb8-ab2d5c945bef/volume/sqlalchemy_1603812264100/work
statsmodels @ file:///opt/concourse/worker/volumes/live/148a0e6d-2163-4103-6ef5-61556693c052/volume/statsmodels_1602280229372/work
sympy @ file:///opt/concourse/worker/volumes/live/d5d0b33b-5c2f-493b-5b67-8149e5531868/volume/sympy_1605119535834/work
tables==3.6.1
tblib @ file:///tmp/build/80754af9/tblib_1597928476713/work
terminado==0.9.1
testpath==0.4.4
threadpoolctl @ file:///tmp/tmp9twdgx9k/threadpoolctl-2.1.0-py3-none-any.whl
tifffile==2020.10.1
toml @ file:///tmp/build/80754af9/toml_1592853716807/work
toolz @ file:///tmp/build/80754af9/toolz_1601054250827/work
tornado==6.1
tqdm @ file:///tmp/build/80754af9/tqdm_1602185206534/work
traitlets @ file:///tmp/build/80754af9/traitlets_1602787416690/work
typing-extensions @ file:///tmp/build/80754af9/typing_extensions_1598376058250/work
tzlocal==2.1
ujson @ file:///opt/concourse/worker/volumes/live/2fc9988c-ebca-4577-6c4b-7383ea76e8ee/volume/ujson_1602523306974/work
unicodecsv==0.14.1
urllib3 @ file:///tmp/build/80754af9/urllib3_1603305693037/work
virtualenv==20.4.2
virtualenv-clone==0.5.4
watchdog @ file:///opt/concourse/worker/volumes/live/cc0ee7bb-1065-44c4-5867-0fd5d13729e0/volume/watchdog_1593447373245/work
wcwidth @ file:///tmp/build/80754af9/wcwidth_1593447189090/work
webencodings==0.5.1
Werkzeug==1.0.1
widgetsnbextension==3.5.1
wrapt==1.11.2
wurlitzer @ file:///opt/concourse/worker/volumes/live/01a17f3d-eafe-4806-57a1-4b9ef5d1815f/volume/wurlitzer_1594753845129/work
xlrd==1.2.0
XlsxWriter @ file:///tmp/build/80754af9/xlsxwriter_1602692860603/work
xlwings==0.20.8
xlwt==1.3.0
xmltodict==0.12.0
yapf @ file:///tmp/build/80754af9/yapf_1593528177422/work
zict==2.0.0
zipp @ file:///tmp/build/80754af9/zipp_1604001098328/work
zope.event==4.5.0
zope.interface @ file:///opt/concourse/worker/volumes/live/de428e3b-00ba-4161-442e-b9e5d25e4219/volume/zope.interface_1602002489816/work
```

Am I suppose to add something in the `Pipfile.lock`?
Does Heroku not work if we install a new package?

Any advice will be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Please provide your `requirements.txt`

Comment: @wowkin2 Edited my post to include that.

Comment: Is that file pushed to Heroku?

Comment: @wowkin2 Yes it is. I have no idea what happened.

Comment: try to remove heroku plugins from app, maybe they can cause anything

Comment: Hey @wowkin2 it's okay I managed to solve it! I've posted the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay managed to solve this!!

1. Remake `requirements.txt` with

```
pipenv shell
pip freeze > requirements.txt
```

New `requirements.txt`:

```
APScheduler==3.6.3
certifi==2020.12.5
python-telegram-bot==13.3
python-google-places==1.4.2
pytz==2021.1
six==1.15.0
tornado==6.1
tzlocal==2.1
```

2. Deleted my existing `Pipfile.lock` and use

```
pipenv lock
```

New `Pipfile.lock`:

```
{
    "_meta": {
        "hash": {
            "sha256": "80d55f91eefe0485b51d373432dee4eb40407661ccfac508d2d41e09b594e3c5"
        },
        "pipfile-spec": 6,
        "requires": {
            "python_version": "3.8"
        },
        "sources": [
            {
                "name": "pypi",
                "url": "https://pypi.org/simple",
                "verify_ssl": true
            }
        ]
    },
    "default": {
        "apscheduler": {
            "hashes": [
                "sha256:3bb5229eed6fbbdafc13ce962712ae66e175aa214c69bed35a06bffcf0c5e244",
                "sha256:e8b1ecdb4c7cb2818913f766d5898183c7cb8936680710a4d3a966e02262e526"
            ],
            "version": "==3.6.3"
        },
        "certifi": {
            "hashes": [
                "sha256:1a4995114262bffbc2413b159f2a1a480c969de6e6eb13ee966d470af86af59c",
                "sha256:719a74fb9e33b9bd44cc7f3a8d94bc35e4049deebe19ba7d8e108280cfd59830"
            ],
            "version": "==2020.12.5"
        },
        "python-google-places": {
            "hashes": [
                "sha256:0046f9c0d80d97838d3d4a554bdfa84c6c26d0b613b3e613598dadfd4b89bad4"
            ],
            "index": "pypi",
            "version": "==1.4.2"
        },
        "python-telegram-bot": {
            "hashes": [
                "sha256:770d6c19f75e530de7f6a8784ec06945da84bcd2344a72932b8c2a05a78cd421",
                "sha256:8b5790cdbd5794da5ee06eb8d0a00a81e3f48b0e04b4d0e33874d45a2495c221"
            ],
            "index": "pypi",
            "version": "==13.3"
        },
        "pytz": {
            "hashes": [
                "sha256:83a4a90894bf38e243cf052c8b58f381bfe9a7a483f6a9cab140bc7f702ac4da",
                "sha256:eb10ce3e7736052ed3623d49975ce333bcd712c7bb19a58b9e2089d4057d0798"
            ],
            "version": "==2021.1"
        },
        "six": {
            "hashes": [
                "sha256:30639c035cdb23534cd4aa2dd52c3bf48f06e5f4a941509c8bafd8ce11080259",
                "sha256:8b74bedcbbbaca38ff6d7491d76f2b06b3592611af620f8426e82dddb04a5ced"
            ],
            "markers": "python_version >= '2.7' and python_version not in '3.0, 3.1, 3.2'",
            "version": "==1.15.0"
        },
        "tornado": {
            "hashes": [
                "sha256:0a00ff4561e2929a2c37ce706cb8233b7907e0cdc22eab98888aca5dd3775feb",
                "sha256:0d321a39c36e5f2c4ff12b4ed58d41390460f798422c4504e09eb5678e09998c",
                "sha256:1e8225a1070cd8eec59a996c43229fe8f95689cb16e552d130b9793cb570a288",
                "sha256:20241b3cb4f425e971cb0a8e4ffc9b0a861530ae3c52f2b0434e6c1b57e9fd95",
                "sha256:25ad220258349a12ae87ede08a7b04aca51237721f63b1808d39bdb4b2164558",
                "sha256:33892118b165401f291070100d6d09359ca74addda679b60390b09f8ef325ffe",
                "sha256:33c6e81d7bd55b468d2e793517c909b139960b6c790a60b7991b9b6b76fb9791",
                "sha256:3447475585bae2e77ecb832fc0300c3695516a47d46cefa0528181a34c5b9d3d",
                "sha256:34ca2dac9e4d7afb0bed4677512e36a52f09caa6fded70b4e3e1c89dbd92c326",
                "sha256:3e63498f680547ed24d2c71e6497f24bca791aca2fe116dbc2bd0ac7f191691b",
                "sha256:548430be2740e327b3fe0201abe471f314741efcb0067ec4f2d7dcfb4825f3e4",
                "sha256:6196a5c39286cc37c024cd78834fb9345e464525d8991c21e908cc046d1cc02c",
                "sha256:61b32d06ae8a036a6607805e6720ef00a3c98207038444ba7fd3d169cd998910",
                "sha256:6286efab1ed6e74b7028327365cf7346b1d777d63ab30e21a0f4d5b275fc17d5",
                "sha256:65d98939f1a2e74b58839f8c4dab3b6b3c1ce84972ae712be02845e65391ac7c",
                "sha256:66324e4e1beede9ac79e60f88de548da58b1f8ab4b2f1354d8375774f997e6c0",
                "sha256:6c77c9937962577a6a76917845d06af6ab9197702a42e1346d8ae2e76b5e3675",
                "sha256:70dec29e8ac485dbf57481baee40781c63e381bebea080991893cd297742b8fd",
                "sha256:7250a3fa399f08ec9cb3f7b1b987955d17e044f1ade821b32e5f435130250d7f",
                "sha256:748290bf9112b581c525e6e6d3820621ff020ed95af6f17fedef416b27ed564c",
                "sha256:7da13da6f985aab7f6f28debab00c67ff9cbacd588e8477034c0652ac141feea",
                "sha256:8f959b26f2634a091bb42241c3ed8d3cedb506e7c27b8dd5c7b9f745318ddbb6",
                "sha256:9de9e5188a782be6b1ce866e8a51bc76a0fbaa0e16613823fc38e4fc2556ad05",
                "sha256:a48900ecea1cbb71b8c71c620dee15b62f85f7c14189bdeee54966fbd9a0c5bd",
                "sha256:b87936fd2c317b6ee08a5741ea06b9d11a6074ef4cc42e031bc6403f82a32575",
                "sha256:c77da1263aa361938476f04c4b6c8916001b90b2c2fdd92d8d535e1af48fba5a",
                "sha256:cb5ec8eead331e3bb4ce8066cf06d2dfef1bfb1b2a73082dfe8a161301b76e37",
                "sha256:cc0ee35043162abbf717b7df924597ade8e5395e7b66d18270116f8745ceb795",
                "sha256:d14d30e7f46a0476efb0deb5b61343b1526f73ebb5ed84f23dc794bdb88f9d9f",
                "sha256:d371e811d6b156d82aa5f9a4e08b58debf97c302a35714f6f45e35139c332e32",
                "sha256:d3d20ea5782ba63ed13bc2b8c291a053c8d807a8fa927d941bd718468f7b950c",
                "sha256:d3f7594930c423fd9f5d1a76bee85a2c36fd8b4b16921cae7e965f22575e9c01",
                "sha256:dcef026f608f678c118779cd6591c8af6e9b4155c44e0d1bc0c87c036fb8c8c4",
                "sha256:e0791ac58d91ac58f694d8d2957884df8e4e2f6687cdf367ef7eb7497f79eaa2",
                "sha256:e385b637ac3acaae8022e7e47dfa7b83d3620e432e3ecb9a3f7f58f150e50921",
                "sha256:e519d64089b0876c7b467274468709dadf11e41d65f63bba207e04217f47c085",
                "sha256:e7229e60ac41a1202444497ddde70a48d33909e484f96eb0da9baf8dc68541df",
                "sha256:ed3ad863b1b40cd1d4bd21e7498329ccaece75db5a5bf58cd3c9f130843e7102",
                "sha256:f0ba29bafd8e7e22920567ce0d232c26d4d47c8b5cf4ed7b562b5db39fa199c5",
                "sha256:fa2ba70284fa42c2a5ecb35e322e68823288a4251f9ba9cc77be04ae15eada68",
                "sha256:fba85b6cd9c39be262fcd23865652920832b61583de2a2ca907dbd8e8a8c81e5"
            ],
            "markers": "python_version >= '3.5'",
            "version": "==6.1"
        },
        "tzlocal": {
            "hashes": [
                "sha256:643c97c5294aedc737780a49d9df30889321cbe1204eac2c2ec6134035a92e44",
                "sha256:e2cb6c6b5b604af38597403e9852872d7f534962ae2954c7f35efcb1ccacf4a4"
            ],
            "version": "==2.1"
        }
    },
    "develop": {}
}
```

Reason being my `Pipfile.lock` wasn't updated to the latest list of dependencies after I added `python-google-places==1.4.2` into my `requirements.txt`.

Thanks to [How are Pipfile and Pipfile.lock used?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46330327/how-are-pipfile-and-pipfile-lock-used)

Answer (score 0):

`Pipfile` is redundant for Heroku. But it is ok to use it for development.

Most probably that you are erasing it from dependencies using `pipenv`. Try to add to `Pipfile` and then do `pip freeze`

```
[packages]
python-telegram-bot = "*"
python-google-places = "*"

[dev-packages]
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip. However It's still the same. `ModuleNotFoundError`