# Same code does not work in venv despite installing dependencies from same requirements.txt

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, python-venv, requirements.txt

I am developing a web application and trying to migrate from Spyder to VS Code.
It was working with the default interpreter, so I created a new venv but when I start the server it does not work with the same code that was working without the venv.
Error description:

```
File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\Flask\app.py", line 77, in index
measurement_mx = rs.all()
AttributeError: 'ResultProxy' object has no attribute 'all'
```

I installed exactly the same dependencies with `pip install -r requirements.txt`.

Can you help me what the solution could be, I could not find this problem unfortunately.

Relevant code snippet:

```
@app.route('/', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def index():  
    with engine.connect() as con:
        rs = con.execute(SQL_string)
        measurement_mx = rs.all() #this is the error line
        measurement_list = []
        for row in measurement_mx:
            measurement_list.append(row._data)
        measurement_list = transpose(measurement_list)
    return render_template('index.html', measurement_list=measurement_list )
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Welcome to StackOverflow!

The issue could be that your `requirements.txt` file may specify what packages to install, but not their exact version, so could you please:

- paste the content of your requirements file?
- check the packages versions between your two virtual environments?

Some thoughts:

- [requirements.txt file may constrain packages versions](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/cli/pip_install/#requirement-specifiers)
- the way to exactly reproduce an environment would be to install from a `lock` file, see for instance [this discussion on `pip.lock` file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46330327/how-are-pipfile-and-pipfile-lock-used#:%7E:text=The%20Pipfile.lock%20is%20intended%20to%20specify%2C%20based%20on,You%20can%20lock%20your%20currently%20installed%20packages%20using))

Now, concerning your exact issue: `ResultProxy` is not an object from `flask` but from `SQLAlchemy`, which [SQLAchemy v1.4 replaced](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/connections.html?highlight=resultproxy#sqlalchemy.engine.Result):

> **class sqlalchemy.engine.Result(cursor_metadata)**
>
> Represent a set of database results.
>
> > New in version 1.4: The Result object provides a completely updated usage model and calling facade for SQLAlchemy Core and SQLAlchemy ORM. In Core, it forms the basis of the CursorResult object **which replaces the previous ResultProxy interface**. When using the ORM, a higher level object called ChunkedIteratorResult is normally used.

(emphasis mine)

Which means you can:

- either fix `SQLAlchemy` version in your `requirements.txt` file,
- or update your code to cope with current `SQLAlchemy` syntax.

Comment: Thank you Joël!

I updated SQLAlchemy to 1.4.20 , then ran into this error message:
"AttributeError: 'sqlalchemy.cimmutabledict.immutabledict' object has no attribute 'setdefault' "

After a bit of Googling, I found that I might need to upgrade Flask-SQLAlchemy as well and that did the job after updating to 2.5.1.

Sorry, I cannot upvote you yet because of my missing reputation but your advice was really helpful!

Comment: You're welcome! Management of version over time is not easy, but is necessary to avoid such surprises :)